# Take product images from cache in admin product grid

Tags: magento

I have added a new column in admin product grid called images, which shows product images as a thumbnail. My problem is that in very long lists my panel gets slow.
This column is in a rewrite of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid, and here is the code:

```
$this->addColumn('thumbnail',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Thumbnail'),
                'type'  => 'image',
                'width' => '75',
                'index' => 'thumbnail'
    ));
```

Well i need this column to take images resized from cache, can anybody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will help you!!

```
$this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Thumbnail'),
            'index' => 'entity_id',
            'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_thumbnail')
    ));


public function callback_thumbnail($value, $row, $column, $isExport) {
    $product_id = $value;
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $url = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(70,70);

    return "<img src='$url' />";
}
```